# regular expression help: break on dash...or not

Tags: regex

Doing URL rewrites in IIS8, and need help with a regular expression.

In a URL like this:

```
mysite.com/wichita-2014-Honda-Ridgeline
```

The following expression works great

```
^wichita-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)$
```

That splits down to an easy

```
/index.php?year={R:0}&make={R:1}&model={R:2}
```

Works great. It breaks on

```
mysite.com/wichita-2014-Honda-CR-V
```

Note the new dash in "CR-V". The solution so far has been to have an exception rule preceeding the more general rule:

```
^wichita-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-CR-V$
```

I've tried

```
^wichita-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$
```

But that returns three matches and R:0 is the whole URL! Obviously, that's not what I want.

I have to imagine there's a better way. I just haven't found it yet, and I'm not strong with regular expressions.

So, to sum up: if possible, I'm looking for a regular expression that:

1. Matches on three terms: year, make, model (just to give them names)
2. Those three search terms are separated by a dash.
3. Term 3 might ALSO contain a dash (or a space, expressed in the URL as a plus sign), which should be taken as part of the term and not a separator.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `^wichita-([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)-(.+)$`, and map the capture groups R:1, R:2, and R:3 to `/index.php?year={R:1}&make={R:2}&model={R:3}`

The `.+` captures everything after the first two capture groups into the 'anything goes' last bucket.

Comment: Missed the obvious. That was exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: @BillinKansasCity Also, you should accept the answers to your various questions or people will stop responding :)

Comment: I'm completely good with that. How? I tried to vote up, but need a "15 reputation", whatever that means. I don't see anything in your post that indicates to me how to "accept" it.

Comment: There should be a hallow checkmark below the up/down arrows on the left side fo the answers -- and I'll give you an upvote to help with that not having enough points thing